# Oracle: How to search and replace the text in column2 with exact value from the column1?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, string-matching, regexp-replace

I have 2 text columns in a table. The requirement is to compare these 2 columns and check whether any text is matching and replace it with the text from the first column. We have to watch for the case.

```
CREATE TABLE search_text(
id  NUMBER(20,0),
text1   varchar2(1000),
text2   varchar2(1000));

INSERT INTO search_text VALUES
(
 100,
 'Inband signaling used in transmission that reduces the available user bandwidth from 1.544 to 1.536 Mbps.',
 'USER Bandwidth >inband Signaling< (TRansmission>'
);
```

The expected outcome for text2 column after replace is

```
"user bandwidth >Inband signaling< (transmission>"
```

Comment: Does it always involve matching upper-case to lower-case words (and vice-versa), or are there other situations where the actual letters are different?

Comment: We have to look for the exact word/text in the text2 column (case insensitive per se). If found, irrespective of the case in the text2 column, we have to replace that word with the text1 case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only SQL. Hierarchical query splits the string into multiple rows, and replaces word by word. Then an aggregate function gets the last row, that contains the accumulated replaces for all words:

```
with t (id, word, text1, text2, replaced_text2, lvl) as
(
select id,
       regexp_substr(text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, 1, 'i'),
       text1,
       text2,
       regexp_replace(text2,
                      '([^[:alpha:]]+|^)' || regexp_substr(text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, 1, 'i') || '([^[:alpha:]]+|$)',
                      '\1' || regexp_substr(text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, 1, 'i') || '\2',
                      1, 1, 'i'),
       1 lvl
  from search_text
 union all
select s.id,
       regexp_substr(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, t.lvl + 1, 'i'),
       s.text1,
       s.text2,
       regexp_replace(t.replaced_text2, 
                      '([^[:alpha:]]+|^)' || regexp_substr(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, t.lvl + 1, 'i') || '([^[:alpha:]]+|$)',
                      '\1' || regexp_substr(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, t.lvl + 1, 'i') || '\2',
                      1, 0, 'i'),
       t.lvl + 1
  from search_text s, t
 where t.id = s.id
       and regexp_count(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+') >= t.lvl + 1
)
select t.id,
       t.text1,
       t.text2,
       max(t.replaced_text2) keep (dense_rank first order by t.lvl desc) replaced_text2
  from t
 group by t.id, t.text1, t.text2
 order by id;
```

Sample execution:

```
FSITJA@db01> with t (id, word, text1, text2, replaced_text2, lvl) as
  2  (
  3  select id,
  4         regexp_substr(text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, 1, 'i'),
  5         text1,
  6         text2,
  7         regexp_replace(text2,
  8                        '([^[:alpha:]]+|^)' || regexp_substr(text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, 1, 'i') || '([^[:alpha:]]+|$)',
  9                        '\1' || regexp_substr(text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, 1, 'i') || '\2',
 10                        1, 1, 'i'),
 11         1 lvl
 12    from search_text
 13   union all
 14  select s.id,
 15         regexp_substr(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, t.lvl + 1, 'i'),
 16         s.text1,
 17         s.text2,
 18         regexp_replace(t.replaced_text2,
 19                        '([^[:alpha:]]+|^)' || regexp_substr(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, t.lvl + 1, 'i') || '([^[:alpha:]]+|$)',
 20                        '\1' || regexp_substr(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+', 1, t.lvl + 1, 'i') || '\2',
 21                        1, 0, 'i'),
 22         t.lvl + 1
 23    from search_text s, t
 24   where t.id = s.id
 25         and regexp_count(s.text1, '[[:alpha:]\'']+') >= t.lvl + 1
 26  )
 27  select t.id,
 28         t.text1,
 29         t.text2,
 30         max(t.replaced_text2) keep (dense_rank first order by t.lvl desc) replaced_text2
 31    from t
 32   group by t.id, t.text1, t.text2
 33   order by id;

  ID TEXT1                                    TEXT2                                    REPLACED_TEXT2
---- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
 100 Inband signaling used in transmission th USER Bandwidth >inband Signaling< (TRans user bandwidth >Inband signaling< (trans
     at reduces the available user bandwidth  mission>                                 mission>
     from 1.544 to 1.536 Mbps.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update search_text 
Set text1   = text2,
    text2= text1
    But before doing so, please create backup, you may loose information. This is working in SQL server, so it will definately work in oracle.

Comment: Doesn't it replace the entire text? I am looking for the specific text to be replaced.

Comment: Yes, it will replcae the entire text , however can you please explain which text you are looking for the change

Comment: We have to look for the exact word/text (single word or multiple) in the text2 column (case insensitive). If found, irrespective of the case in the text2 column, we have to replace that word with the text1 case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in SQL, but - if PL/SQL is OK with you, see if this helps.

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from search_text;

  ID TEXT1                                    TEXT2
---- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
 100 Inband signaling used in transmission th USER Bandwidth >inband Signaling< (TRans
     at reduces the available user bandwidth  mission>
     from 1.544 to 1.536 Mbps.
```

Function: nested loops, comparing word-by-word in both `text1` and `text2` strings. If they match (note the `lower` function along with `regexp_substr` which removes `>`, `(` and such), perform replace.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_replace (par_id in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_text search_text.text2%type;
  5    l_fir  varchar2(100);
  6    l_sec  varchar2(100);
  7  begin
  8    select text2
  9      into l_text
 10      from search_text
 11      where id = par_id;
 12
 13    for cur_fir in (select regexp_substr(text1, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val
 14                    from search_text
 15                    where id = par_id
 16                    connect by level <= regexp_count(text1, ' ') + 1
 17                   )
 18    loop
 19      for cur_sec in (select regexp_substr(text2, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val
 20                      from search_text
 21                      where id = par_id
 22                      connect by level <= regexp_count(text2, ' ') + 1
 23                     )
 24      loop
 25        l_fir := regexp_substr(cur_fir.val, '\w+');
 26        l_sec := regexp_substr(cur_sec.val, '\w+');
 27        l_text := case when lower(l_sec) = lower(l_fir)
 28                            then replace(l_text, l_sec, l_fir)
 29                       else l_text
 30                  end;
 31      end loop;
 32    end loop;
 33
 34    return l_text;
 35  end;
 36  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_replace(100) result from dual;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------
user bandwidth >Inband signaling< (transmission>

SQL>
```